# Возврат значения до наведения курсора

Tags: html, вёрстка, css, javascript

Есть код: 
http://jsfiddle.net/raccoon89/DjLpp/

Но он работает в одном направлении. Нужо сделать так, чтобы мэйл возвращался после отводки курсора от блока. А при наведении поялвлялся номер телефона.

Comment: jQuery решение пойдёт или только Pure JS?

Comment: Лучше jQuery  конечно, но скрипта не нашел такого

Comment: почему-бы css не сделать ? как-то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/jwGqd/)

Comment: Да, неплохо, но задумка немного не такая. Е мэйл должен изменятся на телефон при наведении на иконку, а не сам е мэйл)

Comment: @eicto классно!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/jwGqd/1/

Comment: спасибо огромноее. Посоветуй литертуру по фишкам CSS пжл

Comment: Неудобно, когда нужно дождаться завершения анимации, чтобы телефон можно было скопировать.

Comment: Начинаешь выделять телефон, уходишь мышкой с него - фигакс, это уже не телефон и выделение пропало :(

Comment: А кому нужно выделять телефон?

Comment: Кому угодно, кто захочет его скопировать и сохранить. И это может происходить даже чаще, чем набор "глазами" с экрана.

Comment: анимация для понтов, все равно не решить ни js ни как-то ещё, это usability тема. если transition убрать, то будет работать.

Comment: @Ильяс Билалов https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS
и можно еще http://css-tricks.com/ первый приоритетнее,

для ie http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531209(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @eicto, а чем это удобней для юзера, чем такой вариант:

    Наш телефон: <a href="callto:555">555</a> (звонить с 9 утра до 6 вечера [по Москве|Киеву|GMT], e-mail: <a href="mailto:our@e.mail">our@e.mail</a>

Comment: не моя задача не знаю :)

Comment: @eicto, дык я тоже софт для роботов пишу, давно уже. Но как юзеру - хочется видеть что-то вменяемое и юзабельное человеком, а не игры в пиксельхантинг и баблбрейкер :)

Comment: @klopp ну в запросе было по иконке чтобы менялось значение :)

Answer (score -1):

```
onmouseover="if (document.getElementById('texty').innerHTML!='mail@fuze.pro') {document.getElementById('texty').innerHTML='mail@fuze.pro'} else {document.getElementById('texty').innerHTML='8 912 77 20 444'}" onmouseout="if (document.getElementById('texty').innerHTML!='8 912 77 20 444') {document.getElementById('texty').innerHTML='8 912 77 20 444'} else {document.getElementById('texty').innerHTML='mail@fuze.pro'}"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DjLpp/4/

Comment: @eicto зато можно телефон сразу скопировать :D

Comment: ужос - это у автора в коде, я лишь сделал, что он просил.
http://jsfiddle.net/DjLpp/5/

Comment: @Евгений_21 ужоса вы добавили... захардкоженный if/elseif в разметку...

Comment: @Евгений_21, http://jsfiddle.net/DjLpp/6/